# GROUP BY and ORDER BY issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
s.styleTitle
), COUNT(p.id) AS `PictureCount`
FROM  `style` s
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_picture_style` ps ON s.id = ps.style_id
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_shop_picture` p ON ps.picture_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_picture_category` c ON c.picture_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_second_level_category` sl ON c.second_level_category_id = sl.id
WHERE sl.id =25
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY PictureCount
```

however this query gives me:

[image]

I basically wanted the list to be ordered by the style that has the most pictures in it. What did I do wrong? Why is it giving me 1 on all of the styles, I am pretty sure it has more pictures for that style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY` doesn't have underscores.  But equally important, you are using `DISTINCT` in a way where you seem to think that it is a function.  It is not.  It is a modifies on the `SELECT` and it applies to all columns.

You should `group by` the same column you have in the distinct.  Something like this:

```
SELECT s.styleTitle, COUNT(p.id) AS `PictureCount`
FROM  `style` s
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_picture_style` ps ON s.id = ps.style_id
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_shop_picture` p ON ps.picture_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_picture_category` c ON c.picture_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN  `instagram_second_level_category` sl ON c.second_level_category_id = sl.id
WHERE sl.id  = 25
GROUP BY s.styleTitle
ORDER BY PictureCount DESC;
```

In fact, you almost never need `distinct` with `group by`.  If you are using, you need to think why it would be necessary.